# How to debug audio node connections?

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I'm working on a large scale music app and I'm having trouble with some nodes not connecting and disconnecting properly.

Is there a method in web audio to see a list of current connections a AudioNode has?

I've tried using Firefox's Developer browser as this shows a view of all current connections but the problem is that it's viewer really can't handle more than about 15 connections.

It would be great if there was something like: `osc.connections();` which would return an array of nodes the `osc` is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

If the Firefox tools doesn't do the trick, then I think the answer is no. I think I saw a Chrome extension which did something similar way back, but I can't find any trace of it.

Your best option is probably to keep track of the connections yourself, unfortunately.